# tf.train.write_graph uses all the memory and causes MemoryError

Tags: python, tensorflow

I was trying to export the simple MNIST model graph to proto buffer file in text format.

Actually, I was using `tf.keras` module but then I decided to switch as it was difficult to rename/assign a name to input and output tensors in keras Sequential Model.

**Here goes my code :**

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()

y_train = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train, 10)
y_test = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(y_test, 10)

x_test = np.reshape(x_test, (-1, 784))/255
x_train = np.reshape(x_train, (-1, 784))/255

X = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[None, 784])
Y = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[None, 10])

h1 = tf.get_variable('h1',shape=[784, 16])
b1 = tf.zeros(shape=[16])

h2 = tf.get_variable('h2', shape=[16,10])
b2 = tf.zeros(shape=[10])

l1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(X, h1) + b1)
logits = tf.matmul(l1, h2) + b2

# l1 = tf.layers.dense(inputs=X, units=16, activation=tf.nn.relu)
# logits = tf.layers.dense(inputs=l1, units=10, activation=tf.nn.softmax)

loss = tf.losses.softmax_cross_entropy(onehot_labels=Y, logits=logits)
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.01).minimize(loss)
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(tf.equal(tf.argmax(logits, -1), tf.argmax(Y, -1)), tf.float32))

data_pipeline = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x_train, y_train))
iter = data_pipeline.shuffle(1000).repeat().batch(1024).make_one_shot_iterator()
next_item = iter.get_next()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    for i in range(5):
        for i2 in range(1000):
            x, y = sess.run(next_item)
            if i2 % 100 == 0:
                lss = sess.run(loss, feed_dict={X: x, Y: y})
                print('Loss at {} => {} is {}'.format(i, i2, lss))
                sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={X: x, Y: y})
    print('Final Accuracy : ', sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={X: x_train, Y: y_train}))
    # tf.train.write_graph(sess.graph, './', 'temp.pbtxt')
    # This line here is causing the Memory Error
```

**System Information and Library Information**

- OS: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
- Total Memory : 8.0 GB
- Swap: 4 GB
- Tensorflow 1.8
- Binary Installation

**Some more information**

As I mentioned earlier, when I was using keras, I was easily able to export keras sequential and was able to write the `model.pbtxt` using the session I got from `backend`. The size and configuration of the model were same as this code.

Using tensorflow 1.4, I was able to export and save such models easily even with 4 GB of RAM. Now that I have 8, Why does this throw MemoryError? Sorry for the exact logs, It only showed once, now every time I run this code, my system crashes as it runs out of all the Memory

Also when I am running the code, I get a warning that is :

> 2018-05-16 21:42:08.844531: W tensorflow/core/framework/allocator.cc:101] Allocation of 376320000 exceeds 10% of system memory.

**Questions**

<strike>How can I solve this issue and What causes it?</strike>

---

### EDIT

I removed the tf.data.Dataset with normal numpy modification and everything is working fine. I still want to know, Why does not using tf.data.Dataset fixes this? Does this add extra nodes to the graph that is big? Should we only use these pipelines when training on big data and big machines?

Comment: I figured out that if i don't use tf.data.Dataset, then the code works fine. But i wonder why?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the batch size to a lower value, it should resolve the problem.

For example

```
iter = data_pipeline.shuffle(1000).repeat().batch(256).make_one_shot_iterator()
```

Comment: Bach size only affect the training time. Changing it will not have any effect, in saving model. My training time is fairly quick. Also I alhave already tested with small batch sizes like 64, still the problem persists